# Returning all the Users from the current Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a new Action method that when called it will return all the Active directory usernames  . The asp.net mvc application and active directory are within the same domain (and currently inside the same development machine).
So I have defined the following action method:-

```
public ViewResult Details()
        {
 var c = repository.GetUserDetails3();
return View("Details2",c); }
```

and the following repository method:-

```
public DirectoryEntry GetUserDetails3()
        {   DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "WIN-SPDEV.com")){using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
                {foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
                    {de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry; }}}
return de; }
```

and the following model class:-

```
public class DirectoryUser
    {public Nullable<Guid> Guid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
}}
```

and on the view I have:-

```
@model IEnumerable<TMS.Models.DirectoryUser>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details2";
}

<h2>Details2</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Guid)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Username)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Guid)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Username)
        </td>
```

but when I call the action method I got the following error:-
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TMS.Models.DirectoryUser]'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have link for this action  like follow:

```
/CurrentController/Details?id=1
```

So, for example you can write **ActionLink** as follow:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "ControllerName", new { id = 1})" role="button" data- toggle="modal">
```

Comment: you are right i have updated my code, but i am getting a new exeption

Comment: Create another question with your new problem then.